# DRF Newbie - Stuck in small mistake kindly assist

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I created 1 API its all working fine from all ends.
I created 2nd API the DRF headings title showing the headings of old api where i am doing mistake kindly assist.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Brand, Category


class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'icon',
            'featured_image',
            'url'
        )

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'featured_image',
        )
```

products.url

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', BrandViewSet)
router.register(r'', CategoryViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

product.view

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    """
    API endpoint that allows sites to be viewed or edited
    """
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

There is no error but in brower when i run the API url it shows brand list instead of category list,

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but why do you have the same `r''` in `router.register` calls?

Comment: Actually its dynamically working with urlpatterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the views registered  to the same endpoint. So it resolves the first one it finds.

So do the register to different endpoints like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'brands', BrandViewSet)
router.register(r'categories', CategoryViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

So you can access brands via `127.0.0.1:8000/brands` and categories via `127.0.0.1:8000/categories`